# ImportError: No module named types

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, werkzeug

I am getting below error when I start the httpd server and access the app url -

```
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error] [client 10.209.33.139] mod_wsgi (pid=15425): Target WSGI script '/scratch/gdudwadk/python-projects/newblog/app/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error] [client 10.209.33.139] mod_wsgi (pid=15425): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/scratch/gdudwadk/python-projects/newblog/app/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error]   File "/scratch/gdudwadk/python-projects/newblog/app/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error]     from app import app as application
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error]   File "/scratch/gdudwadk/python-projects/newblog/app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error]     from flask import Flask
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error]   File "/scratch/gdudwadk/python-projects/newblog/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error]     from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error]   File "/scratch/gdudwadk/python-projects/newblog/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error]     from types import ModuleType
[Tue Feb 21 22:01:51 2017] [error] ImportError: No module named types
```

This started happening after my machine was replaced with new one. Previously app was working fine.

Comment: what is your pythonpath?  Have you append your project path to pythonpath?

Comment: @HaifengZhang Yes I did below in wsgi.py file : sys.path.insert(0, "/scratch/gdudwadk/python-projects/newblog/app")

Comment: have you add the virtualenv's site packages to the python execution environment?

Comment: yes that is done as well.

Comment: Your Python virtual environment is for Python 2.6. The problem could be that mod_wsgi is now built for a different newer Python version. You can't mix versions like that and it will cause problems.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton except on the documentation page, it says "Werkzeug requires at least Python 2.6 to work correctly." So his installation is within the right version of Python.  http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/installation/

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton mod_wsgi was also built for python 2.6 version itself.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Basically the default python version itself is 2.6. I really wanted to upgrade to atleast 2.7 but with that yum and mod_wsgi started breaking so I reverted everything back to 2.6

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton well, I found one reference to python2.7 in /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf and thats what was causing the issue. After removing that, the app was up and running.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one reference to python2.7 in /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf and that's what was causing the issue. After removing that, the app was up and running.. Thanks!